# How to unhide Integrity Checker within Field Service Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, field-service-lightning, fieldservice

I am looking to use the Integrity Checker feature from Field Service Lightning but I cannot seem to locate it under Field Service Settings.

I did find a statement within the release notes back in summer 18 that mentions the following:

> The integrity checker, an rarely needed feature, under Scheduled Jobs
>   is hidden by default.

Here is the link to it. [Link to the statement above](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_fslmp_other_enhancements.htm)

How can this functionality be unhidden?

Update: I found a static resource named settingsBundle which contains the following code but is not modifiable.

`$scope.hideIntegrityCheckerAutomator = JSON.parse($scope.settings.GeneralConfig['Hide Integrity Checker Automator'][fieldNames.General_Config__c.Value__c]);`

```
hide-section="hideIntegrityCheckerAutomator"></automators>
```

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on "Integrity Checker" beyond that one blurb you mentioned in the Summer 18 Release Notes.  Can you link to documentation you've found that describes what the feature is?

Comment: Have you reached out to Salesforce support or your AE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a case with Salesforce and received the following information:

> Integrity Checker has become an obsolete tool that is no longer needed
>   within FSL.Integrity Checker is an old version of the current Health
>   Checker in FSL.